# general electrical question (with regards to the LBO pin on the Adafruit boost 500 lipo board to a Raspberry Pi)

Tags: level-translation

So I was getting ready to follow this suggestion [Do bi-directional level converters connect either input directly to ground?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/218427/do-bi-directional-level-converters-connect-either-input-directly-to-ground/218449#218449?newreg=6620ffa63ef24c52a728e0138aa9b6dc)

In order to pull the LBO pin to my GPIO on my RPi to shut down my Pi if my LIPO gets too low. This is the board I'm using.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-powerboost-500-plus-charger

According to the first link the addition of the resistor from the 3.3v  voltage of the pi should show the pi 3.3v. but for the life of me it seems that the Out in the diagram of the first answer whould be seeing 5v from the In listed on the same diagram.... am i correct and im about to put 5v into the GPIO pin of my pi or does it in fact work.... if so why??? i cant seem to find the answer though i may not be using the right terms when searching.

Comment: Please edit the post title. This is not a “general electrical question”. Rather, it’s a specific question involving a particular board/component. The title should reflect the topic of the post.

Comment: Please also fix capitalisation of sentences, proper nouns (Raspeberry Pi) and SI units ("V" for volt) and first word of replacement title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Although the chip’s LBO is open-drain; the LBO signal is pulled up to V<sub>BAT</sub> on-board via a BRT (bias resistor transistor).

From the schematic:
[image: schematic]

So, if you need to level convert the board’s output, follow the advice from Spehro Pefhany:

> If you want 3.3V level, you can use a PNP transistor (eg, 2N4403), emitter to +3.3, base through 3K to the LBO pin, and collector to ground through 1K. Pick the signal off from the collector.

Comment: If I follow you correctly this would show 3.3V to the GPIO( which I  pick up before the 1K resistor?) until it LBO goes to zero then the GPIO would show 0V because the "switch" is off?

Comment: @bpwmd Well, the opposite. For a PNP, the transistor will be ON when the base is driven down to 0V, at which point the collector (i.e. your GPIO signal) will be pulled up to your 3.3V supply to indicate a low battery voltage condition. Otherwise (when the base is high), your PNP will be off, and therefore at ground potential.